# How to increase timeout of discord.py trigger_typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a Discord bot that uses `await ctx.trigger_typing()` to show as typing while it process the command, and it generally works fine, as it will display as typing until the bot sends the message or 10 seconds have passed, whichever comes first. The only problem is, sometimes the bot can take longer than 10 seconds to process, so I was wondering if it was possible to increase the timeout to, say, 20 seconds instead.

Comment: you are probably looking for `ctx.typing()` instead of `ctx.trigger_typing()` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `async with ctx.typing():` (when ctx is a channel/context) and then control the time it is typing with `asyncio.sleep()`/`time.sleep()`, i recommend asyncio because time will freeze your bot so you couldn't use other commands when its sleeping.
Example on command:

```
@bot.command()
async def foobar(ctx):
    async with ctx.typing():
        # do other stuff here
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
    # This line would be executed after 'typing' for x seconds, without 'typing' state
```

Note that you have to place `asyncio.sleep()` after everything so the bot wouldn't wait first.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't this mean that it would always wait for 20 seconds before sending the message? Whereas I'd want it to send the message as soon as it's done processing the command, whether that be after 5 seconds or 15 seconds, and just have it display as typing whilst it's processing the command (as well as having it stop displaying as typing after 20 seconds have passed and it still hasn't sent the message, to prevent it from displaying as typing infinitely if the command gets stuck).

Comment: @Gameskiller01 instead of sleeping for 20 seconds inside the `ctx.typing`, put your code inside `ctx.typing`